# Magento 2 : Overriden UI Component in Custom Theme is not Working

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, overriding

Overriden UI Component in custom theme is not working.
If I delete the existing/original ui_component file then only it is correctly loading from custom theme (from   app/design/../..)

Why this, How to fix it?

Here is the Folder structure:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You Can refer to this answer. This was a solution for me. [Override file solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224240/100035)

Comment: Can you show us how you have overridden it please?

Comment: Hello @BenCrook

I have added the screenshots of folder structure I have followed to override, Please let me know if it is helpful for diagnosis.