# Overwrite magento_theme adminhtml ui_component xml file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, overrides, uicomponent

I am trying to overwrite following file: `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

The changes work when editing the file directly in vendor dir, however, I am having some problems overwriting this file.

I copied the file to following location but it just doesn't work: `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

I ran:

> rm -rf generated/code
>
> rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define This in **module.xml**

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
```

[Component load order](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html)

Comment: This seemed to work! Can you explain I had to add this?

Comment: its specify for load order

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: Great. Thank you! Lesson learned!

Comment: most welcome happy coding....:)

Answer (score 1):

The file has likely been copied to the wrong location. Your theme is either frontend or adminhtml so does not require that distinction in the folder structure.

So instead of
`app/code/Magento/Theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` you'll need something like
`path/to/admin-theme/Magento_Theme/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

Comment: thank you for your answer! I found a solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the **ui_component** using a custom module.

1. So create a `Vendor/Module`. (registration, etc/module.xml, composer.json)
2. Extend the ui_component in your module. `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ui_component_name.xml`

An official example of extending the category form ui_component can be found [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html#step-2-display-the-attribute)

An example of extending the customer_form can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218823/override-base-ui-component-customer-form-xml?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I found a solution in the accepted answer.